# Remove null elements in stack

Tags: c++, data-structures, null, linked-list, stack

I had homework that requests to remove null elements in stack? But I think it's impossible to have a null element in stack in case I define structure:

```
struct element{
  type value;
  element* next;
}
```

`element` only points to null if it is the last.

I highly appreciate any help.
Thanks alot.

Comment: What do you mean by a "null element?"

Comment: First you need a definition of what a "null element" is. Is it an element whose `value` is zero or some other specific value? Anything else?

Comment: It's `value` that makes an element a candidate for removal, not `next`. So you need a value type that can be NULL.

Comment: You're right. I should have a type NULL since I pop(stack), I can compare and remove it. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need a special struct or class for the element contents of a stack. Your `element struct` looks more like something used in a one-way, linked list.

To remove nulls from a stack: Create a 2nd, temporary `stack`. `Pop` the elements from the first `stack` one-by-one and if they are `null` discard them. If not, `push` them onto the new `stack`. To preserve the same LIFO ordering of the items as when you started you would need to populate a new stack, or the original stack, from your temporary stack.

When you have gone through all the elements in the original stack them you will have what the assignment calls for. A stack with all of the null elements removed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I also think about creating the second stack to store when iteration stack 1.

Comment: @user2016446: Please check the updated answer. I added a step that was missing initially to preserve the LIFO ordering.